# Is it possible to not create keyframes automatically when drawing with Grease Pencil?

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil

Is it possible to use the grease pencil without creating keyframes when you draw: I just want a single drawing so I don't need keyframes, but I need to be able to scrub through the timeline when drawing.

I know I can move the keyframes or delete them, but it would be easier not to have any.

I have already tried turning the "automatic keyframe" button from the timeline off.

Comment: To clarify, it is not actually a keyframe. This confused me too. The line showing in the Timeline is actually a lime-green color which denotes the usage of a grease pencil. The keyframe is yellow. I would go into the Blender settings and change the Grease Pencil color in the Timeline to something else, so it isn't confused with a keyframe.

Comment: @TTTTTTa I think technically they still are keyframes, just Grease Pencil keyframes as opposed to regular keyframes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just hit the button to lock the frame in the grease pencil layers panel.

[image]