# Deleting Grease Pencil and grease pencil usage showing up in the Timeline

Tags: grease-pencil, timeline

In the hierarchy I have "GPencil and GP_Layer". I would like to delete this from the hierarchy. But mainly, every time I use the grease pencil, Blender puts a lime-green line in the timeline. I would like to get rid of those too, or at least hide them in the Timeline.

[image]

Comment: I found this question, somewhat related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67761/is-it-possible-to-not-create-keyframes-automatically-when-drawing-with-grease-pe?rq=1    It shows how to delete the GPencil and GP_Layer and use the "Lock" the frame. So that solution solves my problem.

Comment: Also, I originally confused these lines as being keframes, and was confused because they weren't showing up in the Dope Sheet. Then I realized they were the Grease Pencil events showing in the Timeline. I would go into the Blender settings and change the Grease Pencil color in the Timeline to something else, so it isn't confused with a keyframe.